# What is the best way to Upgrade Kendo UI for MVC from Beta to latest release

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have started a project using `Kendo UI` for `MVC BETA` and now I would like to upgrade the project to the new release.

1. What steps do I follow to perform the upgrade?
2. My understanding is that I copy the `new js and css files` but I do this from within VS?
3. Do I delete the old files first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I was able to get my solution upgraded. This may or may not be the best way but it worked for me.

1. Downloaded and installed the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2012 release
2. Opened solution in Visual Studio
3. Opened References and deleted the reference to Kendo.MVC.dll
4. Added new reference to the new Kendo.MVC.dll located in "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2012\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc3\Kendo.Mvc.dll"
5. Right clicked on the project and selected Open folder in Windows Explorer.
6. Navigated to the "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2012\styles" folder and copied all folders and files then pasted them into the Content folder of the solution. Replacing exsisting items as prompted.
7. Navigated to the "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2012\js" folder and copied all folders and files (**except** the jquery.min.js file)  then pasted them into the Scripts folder of the solution. Replacing exsisting items as prompted.

I did have one issue with a hierarchy grid and had to change the code to reflect the code on the Kendo UI documentation page but that was it, everything else works the same.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, its been 3 years now and do we have any automatic update available for Kendo UI for asp.net mvc yet?

Comment: There is an upgrade project option through the Telerik Visual Studio extension. You download the latest Kendo UI to your machine (I used the Telerik Control Panel) and in Visual Studio you open your project/sln, select Telerik -> Upgrade... and the Upgrade Wizard will open and walk you through the steps